# errors: [1] 0: {message: "Undefined offset: 1}

Tags: php

I am receiving an php error `errors: [1]
0:  {
message: "Undefined offset: 1 (Error Number: 8), (File: /Users/akashpatel/Documents/iOS development/RideShare/RideShareAPI/src/frapi/library/Frapi/Controller/Api.php at line 299)"
name: "PHP Notice error"
at: ""
}`.

Below is the code.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_LOGIN'])) 
    {
        list($userId, $apiKey) = explode(':',  base64_decode($_SERVER['HTTP_LOGIN']));

        $this->setUserId($userId);
        $this->setApiKey($apiKey);

        //check against DB
        $sql = "SELECT * from user WHERE id=:userId AND apiKey=:apiKey";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':userId', $this->getUserId());
        $stmt->bindParam(':apiKey', $this->getApiKey());                        

        try 
        {
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->fetchObject();
        }
        catch(PDOException $err)
        {
            echo $err->getMessage();
        }

        if ($user == null)
            throw new Frapi_Error('STATUS_FORBIDDEN');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->userName = false;
        $this->apiKey = false;

        throw new Frapi_Error(
            Frapi_Error::ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_REQUEST_NAME,
            Frapi_Error::ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_REQUEST_MSG,
            Frapi_Error::ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_REQUEST_NO,
            Frapi_Error::ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_REQUEST_HTTP_MSG
        );
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT :***
Sorry everyone. I passed incorrect values. Now I use correct one, but getting error `ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_REQUEST`. May be this is because it goes to else. But not getting what can be the reason. I edited the code.

Comment: Turn of your php notices in your php.ini ...

Comment: @pduersteler You, **OUT**. Do not give this advice. Ever.

Comment: @deceze care to explain your rudeness? Of course it is good to initialize your variables and it helps in debugging, but in this case where the author does not even know what to do when a notice pops up, I feel this is an "advice" for a first step to solve a problem. After that, you can talk about the real problem.

Comment: @pduersteler No, you first talk about the real problem, because the real problem is that the code does not work correctly given the wrong input. Notices are there for exactly that purpose, to NOTIFY the developer about some problem with the code. Turning them off just means you never see the problems and hence can't fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the string did not `explode` into two parts and the resulting array does not have an offset `1`. You should not `list()`-assign variables unless you are 2000% sure you have that many indexes in the array you're assigning. In this case it's out of your control, so you better check first.